# Find a differencing between year for sales

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data that analysing sales. I made some progress and this is the last part I did that show each store sales total for each year (2016-2017-2018).

```
   Store_Key  Year  count   Total_Sales

0   5.0       2016  28      6150.0
1   5.0       2017  39      8350.0
2   5.0       2018  27      5150.0
3   7.0       2016  3664    105370.0
4   7.0       2017  3736    116334.0
5   7.0       2018  3863    99375.0
6   10.0      2016  3930    79904.0
7   10.0      2017  3981    91227.0
8   10.0      2018  4432    97226.0
9   11.0      2016  4084    91156.0
10  11.0      2017  4220    99565.0
11  11.0      2018  4735    113584.0
12  16.0      2016  4257    135655.0
13  16.0      2017  4422    144725.0
14  16.0      2018  4630    133820.0
```

I want to see each store's sales difference between years. So I used pivot table and show each year with a difference column.

```
Store_Key   2016        2017        2018

    5.0     6150.0      8350.0      5150.0
    7.0     105370.0    116334.0    99375.0
    10.0    79904.0     91227.0     97226.0
    11.0    91156.0     99565.0     113584.0
    16.0    135655.0    144725.0    133820.0
    18.0    237809.0    245645.0    88167.0
    20.0    110225.0    131999.0    83302.0
    24.0    94087.0     101062.0    108888.0
```

If stores were constant, I would quickly find the difference when using the difference between columns, but unfortunately each year so many new stores are founding and shutting down.

So my question is: is there any way to get difference in stores with showing new stores and closing stores?

I can find stores with `NULL` values and separate it but I would love to check if there are some better options.

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference between 2017 and 2016, you can do :

```
 df['evolution'] = df['2017'] - df['2016']
```

If you would like to drop lines where there is at least one NaN value, you can remove those lines like this :

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace=False)
```

If you have 0 instead of NaN, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
df.replace(0, np.nan)
```